# Windows Device Uninstall using C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, device

I need to programatically uninstall all Com port devices. The issue is that these Com Port Devices are not present and therefore completely hidden. Meaning, even if you want to uninstall them using device manager, first you have to add `devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices = 1` to your environment variables and then show hidden devices in device manager. Then, you can right click each device and uninstall. I don't want to uninstall the associated driver though. I am adding that variable under advanced system settings, creating and saving a new user variable.

I try to do this with [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272). They can  be found with `devcon findall` but I cannot remove them because the [command to remove](http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/ddtools/devcon_59f7.htm) them fails stating no device has been uninstalled. Also, there is not flag to have it look for non-present devices. If I do a standard `devcon find`, no devices are found (of interest).

So, I am back to being forced to figure out how exactly to do this using my own code and here is where I get stuck. Here is what I have so far:

```
// Get all of the devices
PCTSTR enumType = "PORTS";
HDEVINFO devs = NULL;
devs = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL,enumType,0,DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);

// Loop through the devices
DWORD devCount = 0;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfo;
int enumeratingDevices = 1;
devInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
while(enumeratingDevices){
    enumeratingDevices = SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo (devs,devCount,&devInfo);
    // Uninstall each device
    cout << SetupDiRemoveDevice(devs,&devInfo);
    cout << SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_REMOVE,&devInfo,NULL);
    devCount++;
}
cout << devCount;
SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(devs);
return 0;
```

Right now I am getting an output of `001`. So, basically, `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo()` or`SetupDiRemoveDevice` do not run correctly. I know that the enumeration is working because if I put in `enumType = "USB";` I get ten for the devCount.

Any help or advice would be great.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES` into current process' environment (in your program only; locally)?

Comment: I have added it permanently to the system so it is always present in my environment variables. Maybe I do not understand your question.

Comment: Look at devcon source code, maybe you can change something to get this functionality.

Comment: I have/am and it is very difficult to pick apart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I figured it out after a lot of tinkering and reading.

```
// Get all of the devices
   //This enumeration does not work in general, instead passing
   //complete id of the device is probably best. 
   //It is helpful to know the vendor and device ID
PCTSTR enumType = "PORTS"; 
HDEVINFO devs = NULL;
devs = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL,enumType,0,DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);

// Loop through the devices
DWORD devCount = 0;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfo;
int enumeratingDevices = 1;
/*This line is essential*/
devInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
while(enumeratingDevices){
        enumeratingDevices = SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo (devs,devCount,&devInfo);
        // Uninstall each device
        if(enumeratingDevices){
           SetupDiRemoveDevice(devs,&devInfo);
           devCount++;
        }
}
    //Clean up
SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(devs);
```

I will update this tomorrow when I get to the lab with the exact enumeration I was talking about. However, with this method, you can uninstall virtually any device even if it is not present and just a "ghost" in the registry.

Comment: Do you have a complete example? Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have access to this project anymore.

Comment: @BrandonBearden hi we have an unusual issue where some deployed software caused a build up of driver instances to the point that the driver stops working. Would this code need to execute in admin rights scope?

Comment: @Bibberty - I can't recall off the top of my head, but I don't recall having to elevate privileges. Most regedit's can be done without privilege escalation. You would just have to run a test. Keep in mind, this doesn't remove the drivers, if I recall correctly. However, it does remove the device and there may be flags to remove the driver(s).

Answer (score 0):

i was able to Disable the usb device successfully with your code but
I am unable to Enable the USB using SetupDiunremoveDevice function could please give example on this API to re Enable the device
WINSETUPAPI BOOL SetupDiUnremoveDevice(
HDEVINFO         DeviceInfoSet,
PSP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData
);

Comment: This does not disable the device. It completely removes it from the system. To get the device installed again, you would unplug and plug it back in. There may be a way to trigger this via software, but I don't know how.